# Android ObjectAnimator freezes UI

Tags: android, objectanimator

I'm doing some animation in my application. Works fine except for one small detail. The UI is unresponsive until the animation is completed. I cannot scroll, not do anything else.

I read that putting this in a Runnable is not the solution. So I'm at a lose.

Ultimately I'd like to have each object using a different duration based on the size of the object so the animation runs faster on a smaller circle and slower on a bigger circle.

Here is the code I have to test my animation :

```
    HoleView holeView = (HoleView) view.findViewById(R.id.holeView1);
    ObjectAnimator oa1 = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(holeView, "animationTime", 0, holeView.getAnimationTime());
    oa1.setDuration(holeView.getAnimationTime());

    holeView = (HoleView) view.findViewById(R.id.holeView2);
    ObjectAnimator oa2 = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(holeView, "animationTime", 0, holeView.getAnimationTime());
    oa2.setDuration(holeView.getAnimationTime());

    holeView = (HoleView) view.findViewById(R.id.holeView3);
    ObjectAnimator oa3 = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(holeView, "animationTime", 0, holeView.getAnimationTime());
    oa3.setDuration(holeView.getAnimationTime());

    holeView = (HoleView) view.findViewById(R.id.holeView4);
    ObjectAnimator oa4 = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(holeView, "animationTime", 0, holeView.getAnimationTime());
    oa4.setDuration(holeView.getAnimationTime());

    AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
    animatorSet.play(oa1).with(oa2).with(oa3).with(oa4);
    animatorSet.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using value animator instead:

Create a method that returns a ValueAnimator:

```
 public static ValueAnimator animate(float from, float to, long duration) {
        ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(from, to);
        anim.setDuration(duration);
        return anim;
    }
```

Then where you use it do the following if for instance you want to set the scale of an ImageView called imageView

```
//where 0 is the start value, 1 is the end value, and 850 is the duration in milliseconds
ValueAnimator imageAnimator = animate(0, 1, 850);

imageAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator anim) {
            float scale = (Float) anim.getAnimatedValue();
            imageView.setScaleX(scale);
            imageView.setScaleY(scale);
        }
    });

 imageAnimator.start();
```